# Does disavow solve the problem of removing unnatural links in google search?

Tags: google-search-console, web-hosting, wordpress, web-crawlers

I have created the site and it got hacked by spammer. now there many unnatural links in it if I disavow it the whole domain will it solve my problem what.

Also I have two version of domain `https://example.com` and other is `https://www.example.com`.

The domain with `www.` is spammy. If I disavow full domain than will it harm my domain non-www version. I am confused. need help.

My previous site was running on `www.example.com` after it got hacked I removed entire site and created another with `non-www` version of domain.

Comment: Please help us to understand your problem: your site www.example.com got hacked by a spammer in oder to post links to other pages on it?

Comment: My site got hacked and there are many unnatural and unwanted link in google search for example www.example.com/casino www.example.com/nudephotos. and many more.I want to remove that links. actually i removed entire site and created new site with same domain without www.

Comment: @simon can you help in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are talking about is not unnatural links but being hacked and having wrong pages indexed.

Your domain `www.example.com`has severeal URLs indexed such as `www.example.com/spam`.

What you need to do first is make sure all your adminitrative logins are secured and your CMS is up to date. Make sure noone else has access to your site's configuration.

Next, delete all the unwanted pages.

Third: go to your Google Search Console account and use the "Remove URLs" feature:
[https://support.google.com/sites/answer/100283?hl=en](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2013/10/easier-recovery-for-hacked-sites.htmlhttp://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2013/10/easier-recovery-for-hacked-sites.html?m=1)

Disavowing links is **NOT** intendet to be used for a case ike yours.

See more on this topic on: [Google Webmasters Help Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2vpe.png)

**Edit**
Note that you may need an additional Search Concole Property for your www and non-www-Version of your page.
Simply erasing it and using the non-www-Versiona s your default does not solve the real problem.

**Edit 2**
After cleaning up and setting up the original website you may consider submitting a sitemap.xml to Google to make it recognise all the changes. Find more on this topic at Google's webmasters Help: [https://support.google.com/sites/answer/100283?hl=en](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2013/10/easier-recovery-for-hacked-sites.htmlhttp://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2013/10/easier-recovery-for-hacked-sites.html?m=1)

**Edit 3**
As you just stated Google informed you in their webmaster tools about your site being hacked. Follow their guide on recovering hacked websites:  [Webmasters Central : Easier recovery for hacked sites](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2013/10/easier-recovery-for-hacked-sites.htmlhttp://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2013/10/easier-recovery-for-hacked-sites.html?m=1)

Comment: I have deleted entire site. but still that pages appear ingoogle search what is the problem there.

Comment: Google does not check your page on an hourly base therefore it needs a bit of time to delete the old pages from Google's index. You may try configuring yor webserver to respond a http 410 status code for each of those spam-URLs. This tells the crawler that the page is gone and does not need to be crawled neither indexed anymore.

Comment: my domain http://example.com is not indexing. whats the problem there?

Comment: Please do not mix up questions. let's try to solve your spam question here. if you have further questions on how to get indexed and so on, please look for similiar questions  open a new question.

Comment: ok please tell how to remove all the links of previous site. the site does not exist now but the search result in google still shows the link of my old site.

Comment: Please do as described above. You may submit a New sitemap of your new "repaired" page to make Google crawl it.

Comment: yes i have submitted a new site map. I have build a new fresh site and submitted new sitemap.

Comment: Then it's up to Google to recrawl your page. Have you been informed on the hacking of your page by Google oder did you discover it by yourself?

Comment: I discovered then i went to search console where i saw this 
Hacked site
Some pages on this site may have been hacked by a third party to display spammy content or links. You should take immediate action to clean your site and fix any security vulnerabilities. Learn more.

Comment: Then it's your turn to follow the instructions on filing a recomsideration request. After that Google will check your page again.

Comment: how to do that? @ seb

Comment: Added a link on how-to.  As you see it's important to give as much relevant Information as possible when asking a question. Now following the Google guide will solve your problem.